# ¿Qué reproductor puedo usar en mi web para el formato de stream pls?

Tags: html, stream, pls

Estoy haciendo una web para una radio, y me han pasado la url de su stream, el cual es este: http://173.193.205.96/stream/kmpa.pls?mp=/stream. Quiero saber cómo puedo hacer para reproducir ese audio en la web, antes tenía otro formato y usaba la etiqueta `audio` pero este formato .pls no lo reconoce:

```html
<audio controls="controls" src="http://173.193.205.96/stream/kmpa.pls?mp=/stream">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La etiquetas `audio` y `video` soportan sólo [algunos formatos multimedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Formatos_admitidos_de_audio_y_video_en_html5) (y no todos los navegadores los soportan por igual):

- WebM
- Ogg (Theora Vorbis, Opus o FLAC)
- MP4 H.264 (AAC o MP3)
- MP3
- WAVE PCM (.wav)

Los `.pls` son ficheros de texto que incluyen información sobre el stream y no son soportados por la etiqueta de `audio`/`video`. Por ejemplo, si abres el que añades en tu pregunta, verás que su contenido es el siguiente:

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=1
File1=http://173.193.205.96/proxy/kmpa?mp=/stream
Title1=
Length1=-1
version=2
```

Entonces lo que podrías hacer es extraer la URL del fichero enlazado dentro del `.pls` y crear tu `audio` a partir de esa URL en lugar de la del fichero `.pls`. Con eso ya te debería funcionar:

```html
<audio controls="controls" src="http://173.193.205.96/proxy/kmpa?mp=/stream"></audio>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo fue super útil tu ayuda, me soluciono el problema.